# haproxy-ingress load balance http on non standard port

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy-ingress

I need to scrape a Prometheus exporter running in a pod.  It runs on port 9098, the exporter is working fine and i can manually **scrape** it from the host it is running on.  The issue is with the ingress.  I am trying to get the ingress to allow outside scraping on port 9098 (it is http and TCP).  Here is my ingress yaml.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/balance-algorithm: roundrobin
    ingress.kubernetes.io/maxconn-server: "10"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  name: ingress-ecobee-exporter
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mysupercool.domain.name
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: ecobee-exporter-service
          servicePort: 9098
```

I have specified port 9098 to work in the containers/ports section of my haproxy-ingress.yaml.  And i can see the "load balancer" in the haproxy stats page, but the hosts never listen on port 9098 to redirect the traffic.

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: you mean the haproxy itself listening 9098? you should use [tcp-service](https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/docs/configuration/command-line/#tcp-services-configmap) instead. Otherwise you can use `mysupercool.domain.name:80/443` which haproxy is listening and know how to send the requests to your backend.

Comment: I added it to my tcp-services (I already had it in place for memcached).  I just assumed TCP services was for non http/https services.  So I didn't need an ingress file and it is forwarded directly to the service.

Comment: `tcp` in the haproxy perspective and listening on an arbitrary port. Since http work over tcp, you can use it to expose http services as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAProxy Ingress uses ingress objects to exposes http services in the `bind` configured port; doc [here](https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/docs/configuration/keys/#bind). The configured `servicePort` has the port name or number of the internal service, which does not reflect in the haproxy's listening ports. TLS's sni extension is used here to choose a certificate to start the handshake if using https. The http `Host` header is used to choose an ingress' hostname. That said, you should probably connect to the exporter using `http://mysupercool.domain.name` - provided that this domains resolves to your ingress and this is the only path matching `/` in this domain.

`tcp-service` on the other hand exposes any tcp based services, http/s included, on any arbitrary port number. There is no sni or `Host` header reading - this is a plain L4 TCP proxy. Special care should be taken here: haproxy won't complain if a port number is reused. In this case the kernel will load balance new requests between every conflicting port.

Comment: I missed the bind configured port in the docs, after the explanation and link I understand this completely.  I have been using haproxy for many years, I just have to adjust to a little different way of thinking.